# Strange iframe height behaviour when placed in a table cell

Tags: css, google-chrome, iframe, height, css-tables

I'm having a problem  with `iframe` height when placed within a table cell. Firefox and Chrome set its minimum height at `150px` while Internet Explorer handles lower height. When cell's height is more than `150px`, `iframe` follows nicely.

The interesting thing is that when placed within a `div` its height is correct regardless of `div`'s height being less than `150px` but within a table cell height seems to follow its own rules (set by the browser).

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UP9Th/1/)

Example `iframe` test are as followed:

1. `iframe` in a `div` with height of less than 150px
2. `iframe` in a table cell with height less than 150px
3. `iframe` in a `div` with height more than 150px
4. `iframe` in a table cell with height of more than 150px

### Additional limitation

Since it seems that `iframe` works fine when placed within a `div` that could be a nice solution, but I can't control HTML since it's part of third party controls that render `iframe` within a table cell. Javascript manipulation is of course always an option, but I would like to resolve this by using CSS only. And since container's height is controlled by the third party as well, I can't change `iframe`'s height to fixed height.

Comment: It works as expected in Opera 12…

Comment: @feeela: :D :D :D It works as expected in IE as well. But that doesn't resolve my Chrome and Firefox issue, does it? ;) Thanks for the info though. I haven't tested in Opera. Helpful for future reference anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to set the table and its children to `display: block`.

http://jsfiddle.net/willemvb/aM2Fx/

```
table,
tbody,
tr,
td{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;   
}
```

Or you could use *relative* positioning on the table, and *absolute* on the iframe.

http://jsfiddle.net/eeZHZ/

```
table
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}


table iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid that won't work, because my actual table has more than one row and some with their own element hierarchy... It's actually a window with title bar, content area and status bar. Written by Telerik, so you can imagine what the state of it is. I can't even imagine who buys these things? I've only had bad experience with third party controls...

Comment: Another thing is that you've only set these when height is lower than 150px. otherwise it breaks behaviour in Firefox when height is greater than 150px. That means that I should use scripts... :(

Comment: I improved my answer for multiple td's

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Having a wrapper is easy yes, because `iframe` becomes a child of a block element. but as mentioned in my question I can't control HTML because it's generated by third party component (by Telerik). And if I'd use Javascript to add a wrapper I can as well set calculated static height to my `iframe` hence no need for a wrapper then. The question is: CSS only, no scripts no HTML manipulation.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry, missed that. Do you know how many td's there will be and can they be of equal width?
http://jsfiddle.net/eeZHZ/5/ seems to work, although bit of a hack for Firefox

Comment: It's basically a table with 3 rows and 1 column. Every row therefore takes the whole table width.

Comment: Ok. You actually helped me with that positioning system of absolute and relative combinations. :) At least in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eeZHZ/7/) it works in all three and without hacks and for my example of one column multi row table. I'll have to check whether it also works in my **actual** code. Hopefully in the meantime you can update your code so if things go smoothly I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This 150px limit for an iframe in a table cell has been reported as a bug in the Gecko/Webkit browser engine:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=253363

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=324388

It has also been remarked upon by the Telerik RAD controls dev team (see [here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/window/minimum-height-browser-inconsistency.aspx#1277509)). I haven't found a definitive reason as to why it was decided that 150px is a mandatory minimum, but it does explain the behaviour you were seeing.